# C# Console Application - One line, each word different color?

Tags: c#, colors

is it possible in an console application to display a text with different kind of colors?
So for example i got the text "Hello Word" in **one line** but i want the word "Hello" to be in green and the word "World" in red?

Possible without any NuGets(?) if not, could you recommend a simple NuGet?

Thanks & Kind Regards!

Comment: `Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;` and `Console.ResetColor();` to reset to default colors.

Comment: no, it will not work likes this. With Console.ForgroundColor i will replace the whole line not just each word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Andy has indicated:

```
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.Write("Hello");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Write("World");
```

[image]

Critically, don't `WriteLine` and you won't end up with whole lines per color.. And don't forget `Console.ResetColor()` when you want to return to normal

Comment: It would be nice(r) to have a space and/or comma between the two words, is not?

Comment: Yeah, I just couldn't decide whether the space should have been red or green, so I left it as an exercise for the OP

Comment: Thank you very much! Its acutally pretty easy, but i was allways typing WriteLine... so i wasnt working for me! Thanks!